# DeviceIOControl error with LTFS on Windows

Tags: driver, scsi, lto

I am trying to use my HP LTO drive with the LTFS wizard in Windows.  I get the following errors (Windows 7 32-bit and Windows Server 2008 32-bit):

```
LTFS15000I Starting mkltfs, HP StoreOpen Standalone version 2.2.0, log level 2
LTFS15041I Launched by "mkltfs -f -d TAPE0"
LTFS15042I This binary is built for Windows
LTFS15043I GCC version is 4.6.3
LTFS17087I Kernel version: Windows
LTFS15003I Formatting device 'TAPE0'
LTFS15004I LTFS volume blocksize: 524288
LTFS15005I Index partition placement policy: None

LTFS17085I Plugin: Loading "ltotape_win" driver
LTFS20013I Drive type is HP LTO5, serial number is HU1032BR7D
LTFS20023E Backend SCSI subsystem error from DeviceIOControl (0x57)
LTFS12034E Cannot get maximum device blocksize: backend call failed (-1)
LTFS17160I Maximum device block size is -1
LTFS20023E Backend SCSI subsystem error from DeviceIOControl (0x57)
LTFS12021E Cannot load the medium: failed to get device parameters (-1)
LTFS11093E Cannot format: failed to load the medium (-1)
LTFS20076I Triggering drive diagnostic dump
LTFS20096I Diagnostic dump complete
LTFS20023E Backend SCSI subsystem error from DeviceIOControl (0x57)
LTFS20072E Failed to read mode data (-1)
LTFS20076I Triggering drive diagnostic dump
LTFS20096I Diagnostic dump complete
LTFS17154E Cannot set WRITE MODE: Mode Sense for Device Configuration Extension failed (-1)
LTFS15023I Formatting failed
```

There is no problem using the Library & Tape Tools in Windows, and the drive works fine with both Library & Tape Tools and LTFS on CentOS Linux.

Why does only LTFS on Windows have a problem?  How can I solve this error?